# pandas pythonic way of handling dependency on a previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm facing (yet another time) a situation in `pandas` where, in a given column, a value in a row `n+1` depends on a value from the row `n`. This is quite common and easily handled in Excel, as in the picture attached, where the value in P8 builds on the value from P7.

My question is what is the pythonic way of implementing in `pandas` something like in the attached example? For as long as components of what needs to be computed all sit in one row (e.g., all corresponding to one day), the vectorization offered by `pandas` works great, but what to do if something from a previous row (e.g., yesterday) contributes to the quantity we compute in this row (e.g. today)?

[image: Screenshot of Excel showing calculation that depends on the previous row value: P8 "=P7*(1+O8)"]

Comment: Take a look at [pandas.DataFrame.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) for an approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas can accumulate values with [`.cumprod()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumprod.html) and [`.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) (among others). In this case what you want is the cumulative product of the percentage.

```
returns_acc = df['Effective returns'].fillna(0).add(1).cumprod()
initial = 1000
df.assign(Adjusted=initial * returns_acc)
```

```
   Effective returns     Adjusted
0                NaN  1000.000000
1            -0.0249   975.100000
2             0.0232   997.722320
3             0.0010   998.720042
4            -0.0201   978.645769
```

Comment: I think there's a more accurate term than  "percentage" but I can't remember it right now. Percentage change? Percentage difference?

Comment: I'd go with change

Answer (score 1):

You have dependent variables so this is very hard to vectorize. But you can make your own function:

```py
def get_values(effective_values, starting_value=1000):
    curr = starting_value
    yield curr
    for v in effective_values[1:]:
        yield (curr := (1 + v / 100) * curr)

data = {"Effective returns": [np.nan, -2.49, 2.32, 0.10, -2.01]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["Values"] = list(get_values(df["Effective returns"]))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Effective returns       Values
0                NaN  1000.000000
1              -2.49   975.100000
2               2.32   997.722320
3               0.10   998.720042
4              -2.01   978.645769
```

Comment: IMO it's cleaner without the walrus: `curr *= 1 + v/100; yield curr`